# Is it safe to run "conda update anaconda" if some packages will be downgraded or removed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

This is the output when I run `conda update anaconda`.

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-slugify-1.2.6       |             py_0           6 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:           6 KB

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  text-unidecode-1.2-py_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  python-slugify                                 3.0.3-py_0 --> 1.2.6-py_0
```

In the past, I never see packages going to be removed and/or downgraded when I run this command. Should I proceed if some packages will be downgraded or removed? But if I don't proceed, how am I going to update anaconda packages in future?

I am running python v3.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: tldr: It is not safe to do so unless you know for certain none of the other packages you have installed do not depend on those dependencies, or any other programs that use those packages will error out.

Comment: thanks for the tip. But I have a dilemma. If I don't run it, how am I going to upgrade anaconda in future?

Comment: Looking at the actual dependencies of `text-unidecode-1.2-py_0`, I find it rather puzzling why it would need to be removed. I'd be interested to know what the solver would do if you first [pinned this package](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) and tried running the update again.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. The solution works on my PC.

Run the following commands on Windows 10;

```
$ conda update anaconda
$ conda install text-unidecode
$ conda update python-slugify
```

After running the commands, text-unidecode is reinstalled, python-slugify is upgraded back to its latest version but text-unidecode is downgraded to a lower version.

So far, nothing breaks on my anaconda package. Everything is tested to work fine.

I emphasize this works on my PC. I cannot guarantee this answer works for other people who encounter the same issue as me.